# How can i compare two Lists ? <long[]> and <int> indexs

Tags: c#

This is the code:

```
var numbers =
               lightningsRegions.SelectMany(
          s => Regex.Matches(s, @"\[(\d+)[ -]+(\d+)\]")
               .Cast<Match>()
               .Select(m => m.Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value)
                                                          .ToArray())
               .Select(x => new { start = int.Parse(x[0]), end = int.Parse(x[1]) })
               .SelectMany(x => Enumerable.Range(x.start, x.end - x.start + 1))
        )
       .ToList();


                for (int i = 0; i < list_of_histogramsR.Count ; i++)
                {
                  if (list_of_histogramsR[i] == numbers[i])
                    {

                    }
                }
```

I consider the variable numbers as number of indexs. In the end numbers contain 5372 numbers.
So each number from thr 5272 is like an index.

Now i have this `List<long[]> list_of_histogramsR` wich contain 16595 indexs.
I want to check that if any number from numbers is in `list_of_histogramsR` as index number then do something.

For example the first number in numbers is 41. So when index number 41 of list_of_histogramsR == to the number 41 in numbers do something. Then the same for the next numbers in the variable numbers.

The problem is that on the IF line im getting error: Error 33 Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'long[]' and 'int'

Why ?

Comment: Btw that error you're getting is because list_of_histogramsR is an array that contains an array for each item while your numbers was an array that contained integers. So you're comparing an array (long[]) to an integer and that is the error you were getting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Contains` to check if the list contains a specific number (cast the int to a `long`):

```
list_of_histogramsR[i].Contains((long)numbers[i])
```